# ¿Cómo puedo identificar frames con selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

Código del frame:

Lo intente de esta manera pero no funciona:

driver.switch_to_frame('nav_panel_div')¿

¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Estás intentando identificar el elemento de alguna página en particula?, si es así, podrías compartirla sí es una url pública?. Quizás esto podrá ayudarte https://stackoverflow.com/a/28723274/11539076

Answer (score 0):

El switch_to_frame de Python espera que le pases directamente el WebElement en este caso el frame, ya localizado:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('tu selector')))
```

O si es el name, seria por ejemplo:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('name del objeto'))
```

No olvides nunca que despues de terminar tus acciones sobre cualquier frame tienes que volver al anterior:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

perdí un montón de horas ayer con un tema similar, igual no es tu caso...

Hacía igual que tú un :

```
self.driver.switch_to.frame('frameFormulario')
```

Y después, dentro del frame cambiaba una opción de un combo. Esto funcionaba bien:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30000).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "respuesta")))
self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "respuesta").click()

dropdown = self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "respuesta")
print("Clicamos en el combo de Aprobar")
```

Ahora viene el poltergeist. Intentaba buscar un botón y hacer click en él, y no funcionaba. Al final pensé en hacer un método alternativo que es pulsar ENTER encima y funcionó:

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnGuardar")))
element.click()    # Esto no me funcinaba
element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)   # Esto sí funcionaba
```

Aunque no sea tu caso, lo que quiero decir es que puedes verificar con otros componentes dentro del frame que en realidad sí puedes acceder al frame, y si, como en mi caso te estás empecinando con el acceso a alguno de los componentes del iFrame... igual deberías buscar otra forma de acceder a él.

También me he acostumbrado a usar indiscriminadamente el "WebDriverWait" para esperar a que lo elementos aparezcan en pantalla, por si acaso...

Espero que te ayude!